# unix command to count the values in one of the column and add this value to last column in each row

Tags: unix, sed, awk

The *.txt* file with tab seperated delimiter, has 4 columns with many no of rows, each of which is of form:

```
12345  a  xxx   yyy  
12345  b  xxx   yyy     
67890  c  xxx   yyy  
12345  d  xxx   zzz   
67890  e  xxx   zzz  
12345  f  xxx   zzz  
23456  g  xxx   zzz
```

How to count instances of each unique integer in the entire first column in the *.txt* file, and add the count as the fifth value in each row by appending fifth column to the *.txt* file.

```
12345  a  xxx   yyy  1  
12345  b  xxx   yyy  2     
67890  c  xxx   yyy  1   
12345  d  xxx   zzz  3   
67890  e  xxx   zzz  2  
12345  f  xxx   zzz  4  
23456  g  xxx   zzz  1
```

I prefer a solution using only UNIX command line stream processing programs.Any help is much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { OFS = "\t"; }
    { 
        key[ $1 ]++;
        print $0, key[ $1 ];
    }
' infile
```

Output:

```
12345  a  xxx   yyy     1
12345  b  xxx   yyy     2
67890  c  xxx   yyy     1
12345  d  xxx   zzz     3
67890  e  xxx   zzz     2
12345  f  xxx   zzz     4
23456  g  xxx   zzz     1
```